# Divide case by population

Tags: r, tidyr

In the table2 dataset from the tidyr package, we have:

```
  country  year       type      count
         <chr> <int>      <chr>      <int>
 1 Afghanistan  1999      cases        745
 2 Afghanistan  1999 population   19987071
 3 Afghanistan  2000      cases       2666
 4 Afghanistan  2000 population   20595360
 5      Brazil  1999      cases      37737
 6      Brazil  1999 population  172006362
 7      Brazil  2000      cases      80488
 8      Brazil  2000 population  174504898
 9       China  1999      cases     212258
10       China  1999 population 1272915272
11       China  2000      cases     213766
12       China  2000 population 1280428583
```

How do I code this so that I can divide the type cases by the type population and then multiply by 10000. (Yes, this is a question from R for Data Science by Hadley Wickham.)

I've thought of:

```
sum_1 <- vector()
for (i,j in 1:nrow(table2)) {
  if (i %% 2 != 0) {
    sum_1 <- (table2[i] / table2[j]) * 10000
```

Comment: What is the expected result suppose to look like?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the resulting dataset should be a tibble with a new column (rate) and ideally, have values computed by dividing counts for cases by counts for populations and multiplied by 10000 grouped by each country for each year.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik is this confusing you? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there are only 2 values for 'type' for each 'country', 'year', then after grouping by 'country', 'year', `arrange` by 'type' (in case the order is different) and divide the `first` value of 'count' with the `last` value of 'count' to create the 'newcol'

```
library(dplyr)
table2 %>%
    group_by(country, year) %>%
    arrange(country, year, type) %>% 
    mutate(newcol = 10000*first(count)/last(count))
```

If we need only a summarised output, replace `mutate` with `summarise`

---

If there are other values in `type` in addition to 'cases' and 'population', then we subset the 'count' based on logical index

```
table2 %>% 
   group_by(country, year) %>% 
   mutate(newcol = 10000*count[type=="cases"]/count[type=="population"])
```

Here, also the assumption is that there is only a single 'cases' and 'population' per each 'country', 'year'

Comment: Thanks!!! This works fabulously. However, I don't understand what part of your code enables me to calculate the rate for each year and country.

Comment: @JasonJoonWooBaik  It is the `group_by` which makes sure that we use only the 'count' values from that particular 'country' and 'year'